# Error: Element type is invalid: Rendering Class within a Class

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was working on the default React Page Source.js and am trying to render another component with the default App

This is the error

> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

and this is my code.

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import React from 'react';
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card';


class SimpleCard extends React.Component{
   render (props) {
      return(
          <Card>
             <Card.CardTitle>
                {this.props.name}
             </Card.CardTitle>
          </Card>
      );
   }
}

class App extends React.Component{
   renderSimpleCard(newName) {
      return <SimpleCard name="newName"/>;
   }

render(){
   return(
      <div className="App">
         <header className="App-header">
            <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
      <p>
         Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
      </p>
      <a
        className="App-link"
        href="https://reactjs.org"
        target="_blank"
        rel="noopener noreferrer"
      >
        Learn React
      </a>
      <div>{this.renderSimpleCard("test")}</div>
   </header>
   </div>
  );
 }
}

export default App;
```

Is there something wrong with my import code or is there something else I need to change.  Like in my package.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Card.CardTitle` component doesn't exist in [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io). It should be [`Card.Title`](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/cards/#title-text-and-links) instead.

```
<Card>
  <Card.Title>{this.props.name}</Card.Title>
</Card>
```

And the `renderSimpleCard` method should pass the `newName` variable to the `SimpleCard` component in the `name` prop (Your code is passing the string `'newName'`).

```
renderSimpleCard(newName) {
  return <SimpleCard name={newName} />;
}
```

Also, note that the `render` method doesn't receive any arguments.

```
render (props) {
  // ...
}
```

should be

```
render() {
  // ...
}
```

[image: Edit card]

Comment: Thanks, that fixed all my problems.  Sorry for the trival questions

Comment: @P.Huang No worries!